# Node.JS one of three same-structured paths is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, backend

I am pretty new to Node.js and I am currently building a backend api for a project. I´ve got 3 routes in my app. societies, users and emails.

```
   //module for email stuff
   emailsModule = require('./api/routes/emails')(connection);
   const emailsRoutes = emailsModule.router;
   app.use('/emails', emailsRoutes);

   //module for societies
   societyModule = require('./api/routes/societies')(connection);
   const societyRoutes = societyModule.router;
   app.use('/societies', societyRoutes);

   //module for users
   usersModule = require('./api/routes/users')(connection);
   const usersRoutes = usersModule.router;
   app.use('/users', usersRoutes);
```

The `societies` and `emails` modules are working, but the emails module is not working.
I just cannot figure out why it isn´t working, I have tried various things but the emails module just doesn´t work. Postman output says "Cannot GET /emails/.
This is my module.exports function:

```
module.exports = function(connection) {
    module.connection = connection;
    sql = connection;
    module.router = router;
    console.log("sacramento");    //test output
    return module;
}
```

An example route is

```
router.get("/:email"), (req, res) => {
    var credentialCheck = new sql.Request();
    credentialCheck.input("email", sql.VarChar, req.query.email);
    credentialCheck.input("passwort", sql.VarChar, req.body.password);
    credentialCheck.execute("checkSocietyCredentials",
    (er, result) => {
        if ( er ) {
            res.status(200).send({
                error:er
            });
        }
        else {
            res.status(200).send(
               {
                   isEmailValid    : result.recordsets[0][0],
                   isPasswordValid : result.recordsets[0][1]
               } 
            );
        }
    });
}
```

It could be just a little stupidity error like // in a path.
The URL i am using for this module is `http://localhost:3000/emails/?email=example@gmail.com`. I I would be really thankful if someone would find the error in my script.

Comment: This syntax is wrong: `router.get("/:email"), (req, res) => {`.  It should be `router.get("/:email", (req, res) => {` and then you will have to add ` )` at the end of the function's code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see multiple issues that will need to be corrected.

This syntax is wrong:

```
router.get("/:email"), (req, res) => {
```

It should be

```
router.get("/:email", (req, res) => {
```

and then you will have to add `)` at the end of the function's code.

You were essentially just defining a route for:

```
router.get("/:email")
```

with no route handler at all.  And, then you were declaring an arrow function, but not doing anything with it.  Assuming this actually parsed in the interpreter, you just got unlucky in that a typo that messed up your code just happened to compile and not report an error (happens sometimes in all languages, more often in a non-typed language).

---

Also, with:

```
app.use('/emails', emailsRoutes)
```

and

```
router.get("/:email")
```

The route you request should be `/emails/someEmail` where `someEmail` is whatever you want the `:email` parameter to be.  If that's an actual email address, it will have to be properly URL encoded.

---

And, in that `/:email` route handler, you are referring to `req.body.password`. That will not work.  `req.body` is empty for a GET request.  That is only used for a POST or PUT request and will only be filled in if you use the right middleware o read and parse the body into `req.body`.

If you are intending to pass both an email and a password to this route, then it should probably be a POST request and both email and password should arrive in the body.

Comment: Oh thanks, I knew it was a typo or something. I didn´t expect that fast help, thank you!t

Answer (score 0):

This is because you defined an email route parameter as a sub route of `/emails`.

Therefore the expected url should be something like this `http://localhost:3000/emails/example@gmail.com`.

You have two options.

1. change the route definition to `router.get("/", ...)`
2. leave your route definition as `router.get("/:email", ...)`, change the url to be like the example above and access the email like so `req.params.email`

I guess you are using express. Check the routing documentation [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) for more information regarding route parameters.

Comment: I also thank you for your help, but I can only give 1 user the correct answer. I just mixed the 2 different route definition and the way I have to pass the params.